# JavaNIO multithreaded server not working

Tags: java, debugging, nio

Hello Experts
can somebody please indentify the problem with this server why this is unable to connect more then one client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.*;

public class MultithreadedServer extends Thread {

    private ServerSocketChannel ssChannel;

    private Thread tRunSer = new Thread(this, "ServerSelectThread");

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        new MultithreadedServer();
    }

    public MultithreadedServer() throws Exception {
        this.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {

                ssChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
                ssChannel.configureBlocking(false);
                int port = 2345;
                ssChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

class Connect extends Thread {
    private ServerSocketChannel ssChannel;
    private SimManager SM;
    private BallState BS = new BallState(10, 5);

    public Connect(ServerSocketChannel ssChannel) {
        this.ssChannel = ssChannel;

        SM = new SimManager(BS);
        SM.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            SocketChannel sChannel = ssChannel.accept();
            while (true) {
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sChannel
                        .socket().getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject(BS);
                System.out.println("Sending String is: '" + BS.X + "'" + BS.Y);
                oos.flush();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

my intention is to send the objects on network.

please help

new code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.*;

public class MultithreadedServer extends Thread {

    private ServerSocketChannel ssChannel;
    private SimManager SM;
    private BallState BS = new BallState(10, 5);
    private Thread tRunSer = new Thread(this, "ServerSelectThread");

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        new MultithreadedServer();
    }

    public MultithreadedServer() throws Exception {
        this.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        // create the server socket once
        try {
            ssChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            ssChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            ssChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(2345));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (true) {
            // accept new connections on the socket

            SocketChannel accept;
            try {
                accept = ssChannel.accept();
                ObjectOutputStream oos;
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(accept.socket().getOutputStream());

                oos.writeObject(BS);
                System.out.println("Sending String is: '" + BS.X + "'" + BS.Y);
                oos.flush();

            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not doing nonblocking IO at all here, as you are simply using the Socket and its stream again. And you should close the stream and Socket when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Also, your `tRunSer` is doing nothing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new server socket for each loop iteration (using the same port over and over). You must create the server socket only once, and then accept new incoming connections.

Something like:

```
 public void run() {
    // create the server socket once
    ssChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    ssChannel.configureBlocking(false);
    ssChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(2345));

    while (true) {
        // accept new connections on the socket
        try {
            SocketChannel accept = ssChannel.accept();
            System.out.println("new client: " + accept.getRemoteAddress());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SPeei: added the new code will that serve my aim, that is throwing NPE

Comment: @Static: Where does it throw the NPE? Show the stack trace (add it to the question), and indicate which line of your code the line numbers correspond to.

Answer (score 0):

If you put something in your catch block you will probably find it yourself. (e.printStackTracer() might help for the time being).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reason for your NPE:

> If this channel is in non-blocking mode then this method will immediately return null if
>   there are no pending connections.

This is from [ServerSocketChannel.accept()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ServerSocketChannel.html#accept%28%29).

Your accept call returns `null`, and you then try to call a method on this `null` object.

Comment: thanks a lot. then what is the solution? i wanted to send the object to multiple clients, that is my concrete problem.

Comment: You have to wait until there really are clients. You can either use a blocking ServerSocketChannel (which waits in `accept` until a client connects), or a Selector, on which you can wait until any of the associed channels are ready for an IO action.

Comment: To send the same data to multiple clients, you could serialize to a ByteArrayOutputStream, and then use nonblocking IO on each of the SocketChannels to send the byte-array. Or do it as you have done now, but there you don't really need non-blocking IO (as you are using a (blocking) OutputStream anyway).